# Selected values and List<SelectListItem> become null after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Please help me to fix the following issue. The selected items from the dropdown become null. Also, when the object is inspected, the List also become null after submitting the form. I tried changing this to an IEnumerable still doesn't work.

**Conroller**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Xmoor.DataAccess;
using Xmoor.Main.Areas.Manager.ViewModels;
using Xmoor.Models;

namespace Xmoor.Main.Areas.Manager.Controllers
{
    [Area("Manager")]
    [Authorize(Roles ="Manager")]
    public class RoleOpenningsController : Controller
    {

        private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> 
 _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> 
 _signInManager;

        public RoleOpenningsController(ApplicationDbContext db,UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager= userManager;
            _signInManager  = signInManager;
            _db = db;
        }
        [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            RoleOpenningsDashboardVM dashObj = new RoleOpenningsDashboardVM();

            dashObj.RoleOpennings = _db.RoleOpennings.Where(r => r.IsClosed == false);

            return View();
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
        public IActionResult CreateNew()
        {
            NewRoleVM roleVMObj = new NewRoleVM();
            roleVMObj.RoleList = _db.Roles.Select(
                    i => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = i.RoleName,
                        Value = i.RoleId.ToString()
                    }
                ).ToList() ;
            roleVMObj.DepartmentList = _db.Department.Select(
                    i => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = i.Name,
                        Value = i.Id.ToString()
                    }
                ).ToList();
            roleVMObj.RoleOpenning = new RoleOpennings();
            return View(roleVMObj);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
        public IActionResult CreateNew(NewRoleVM roleVMObj)
        {
            if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
            {
                roleVMObj.RoleOpenning.Published = true;
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View(roleVMObj);
                }
                _db.RoleOpennings.Add(roleVMObj.RoleOpenning);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")]
        public IActionResult SaveDraft(NewRoleVM roleVMObj)
        {
            if (_signInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
            {
                roleVMObj.RoleOpenning.Published = true;
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    return View("CreateNew", roleVMObj);
                }
                _db.RoleOpennings.Add(roleVMObj.RoleOpenning);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            } 
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

    }
}
```

**Html Code  (.cshtml file)**

```
@using Xmoor.Main.Areas.Manager.ViewModels;
@model NewRoleVM

@section CSS{
    <style>
        .mainContainer {
            text-align: centre;
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 20px !important;
        }

        #registerForm {
            display: grid;
            width: 100%;
            grid-template-columns: 40% 40%;
            max-width: 1000px;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            column-gap: 30px !important;
            row-gap: 20px;
        }

        #buttonContainer {
            width: 100%;
            display: flex;
            grid-column: 1/span 2;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .span2{
            grid-column:1/span 2;
        }

    </style>
}


<div class="mainContainer">
    
    <form id="registerForm" method="post"  asp-action="CreateNew">
        <h1 class="span2">Create New Job Application</h1>
        <label asp-for="RoleOpenning.RoleId"></label>
        <select asp-for="RoleOpenning.RoleId" asp-items="@Model.RoleList">
            <option selected disabled>PLEASE SELECT</option>
        </select>

        <label class="span2" asp-for="RoleOpenning.Description"></label>
        <textarea  class="span2" asp-for=RoleOpenning.Description rows="30" style="width:100%;resize:none;padding:10px;"></textarea>

        <label  asp-for="RoleOpenning.DepartmentId"></label>
        <select asp-for="RoleOpenning.DepartmentId" asp-items="@Model.DepartmentList">
            <option selected disabled>PLEASE SELECT</option>
        </select>

        <label asp-for="RoleOpenning.OpeningDate"></label>
        <input  asp-for=RoleOpenning.OpeningDate type="date" id="txtDate"/>

        <label asp-for="RoleOpenning.CloseDate" ></label>
        <input  asp-for="RoleOpenning.CloseDate"  type="date" id="txtDate"/>

        <div id="#buttonContainer">
            <button type="submit">PUBLISH</button>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>

@section Scripts{
    <script>
         
        $(function(){
        var dtToday = new Date();
    
        var month = dtToday.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = dtToday.getDate();
        var year = dtToday.getFullYear();
        if(month < 10)
            month = '0' + month.toString();
        if(day < 10)
            day = '0' + day.toString();
    
        var maxDate = year + '-' + month + '-' + day;

        // or instead:
        // var maxDate = dtToday.toISOString().substr(0, 10);

        alert(maxDate);
        $('#txtDate').attr('min', maxDate);
        });
    </script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
}
```

**View Model**

```
public class NewRoleVM
{
    public RoleOpennings RoleOpenning { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> DepartmentList { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> RoleList { get; set; }
}
```

**Main model**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Xmoor.Models
{
    public class RoleOpennings
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }


        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Role Name")]
        public int RoleId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(RoleId))]
        public Roles Roles { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Department")]
        public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof(DepartmentId))]
        public Department Department { get; set; }

        public int EditorId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey(nameof (EditorId))]
        public StaffPersonalDetails staffPersonalDetails { get; set; }


        [DisplayName("Opening Date")]
        public DateOnly? OpeningDate { get; set; } = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now);

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Closing Date")]
        public DateOnly? CloseDate { get; set; }

        public bool Published { get; set; } = false;

        public bool IsClosed { get; set; } = false;

        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Description")]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string? Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please see the image to see how object of the viewmodel (NewRoleVM) gives null references for

- DepartmentList
- RoleList

and

- RoleId
- DepartmentId

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND78G.png)

The newRoleVM in HttpPost IActionResult method have a null reference for :

- DepartmentList
- RoleList
- DepartmentId
- RoleId
  after submitting.

How ever the DepartmentList and the RoleLost appears to be correctly working the form before submitting it as it displays all the options in the select list correctly.

Comment: probably need to see full .cs file and .cshtml file... but "asp-for="RoleOpenning.DepartmentId" " doesn't map to anything I can spot.  You could initialize something called "DepartmentID" and bind to that... just set asp-for="DepartmentId".  Or use the main model... but you should include full code so we can see directives and main class vars.

Comment: @pcalkins thank you for your replay. I have amended the code snippet as you requested. Could you check this kindly please ?

Comment: When the SelectList is sent back (posted) you'll only get one value.  So 1 departmentID and 1 roleID.  It looks like those are coming through.  ("1" is the value for each in your screenshot)  Those lists will only be used to set the <option>s... you won't be storing those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The selected items from the dropdown become null. Also, when the
> object is inspected, the List also become null after submitting the
> form

It would be great if you could have specified which view you have shared in **Html Code (.cshtml file)** whether, its for CreateNew Get or Of Index View.

However, assuming its for CreateNew Get action. If so I think you are getting exception on your post method after saving operation once you are redirecting to your **return RedirectToAction("Index");**. you are probably getting as following:

Your error:

[image]

Why exception encountered:

Within your Index action, you have intialized **RoleOpenningsDashboardVM** and passing **RoleOpennings** so far so good. But what's in view? You haven't shared that.

Furthermore, if you have any dropdown there for instance, either department or role list it would definately encounter [NullReferenceException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullreferenceexception?view=net-7.0) becuse you haven't passed any value while calling **public IActionResult Index()** action.

How to Resolve:

If you have any dropdown within your **public IActionResult Index()** action. you have to pass the value same way you did within your **CreateNew()  [HttpGet]** action. It would resolve your issue. You ought to pass value as per your RoleOpenningsDashboardVM Model defination or allow null value to them to avoid the exception.